# MySQL Display Date with nth

Tags: mysql

In mysql there is `NOW()` which will output the date today. My question is how can I format that like this. Example date today 14th of June, Year 2018

Comment: you can see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

Comment: Do a little research before asking

Comment: bad feedback but still thnx for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another version using `DATE_FORMAT`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%D of %M, Year %Y')
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/42020)

Comment: can i ask a question?

Comment: @NardongBagsik yes off course

Comment: I am trying to combine it in my string for example `SET value = "string1" + SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%D of %M, Year %Y') + "string2"` it gives me an error of `Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:`

Comment: You are doing it with Mysql  or any programming language ? It would be good if you can ask a new question but this time please do include all the details like piece of code and error details

Comment: Noted on that I will ask a new one.

Comment: here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50851686/combine-date-formatted-and-string-in-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%M %D, %Y') FROM dual;
```

outputs:

```
June 14th, 2018
```