# Combine Date formatted and String in Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a sample code here..

```
DECLARE d_progcode VARCHAR(6);
DECLARE d_header VARCHAR(30);
DECLARE d_body LONGTEXT;
DECLARE d_date VARCHAR(50);
SET d_progcode = "SAMPLE";
SET d_header     = "Sample Confirmation";
SET d_body        = "String 1" +  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%D of %M, Year %Y')  + ". String 2";
INSERT INTO sample_email (`prog_code`,`sto`,`ssubject`,`sbody`,`datecreated`) VALUES (d_progcode,sto_email,d_header,d_body,NOW());
```

I am trying to combine string and date formatted but when I insert it in table there is an error

`Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value`

Answer (score 1):

In mysql if you want to concatenate string values you need to use `concat`

```
SET d_body = concat("String 1" , DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%D of %M, Year %Y')  , ". String 2");
```

Comment: that did the job. tysm